Visual Studio getting error "C++ CodeDOM parser error: Unknown type 'auto'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced
I inherited this code base and been asked to make it work and I am a new to Visual Studio. In both Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 I get

C++ CodeDOM parser error: Line ??, Column ??. Unknown type 'auto'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been built.

The error points to the first line:
auto tab_control = gcnew Forms::TabControl();

MifEditorPanel^ InitializeMifButtons();

tab_control->Controls->Add(initialize_tp_page());
tab_control->Controls->Add(initialize_mif_page());

tab_control->Dock = Forms::DockStyle::Fill;
Controls->Add(tab_control);

This error happen when I try to open the MainForm.h[Design]
The code compiles.
If this file is looking for where auto is defined I am not sure what reference to give it.
If I commit out this code the error goes to the next reference to the type auto in the file.
I have added the reference to System.Windows.Forms but that did not help.
I also found a blog with the same error and their fix was to switch the .Net Target Framework from 4.61 to 4.5.2 but that did not help either.
I am wondering if auto is not part of the managed language?
I would appreciate if someone could explain why I am getting this error and how to solve it.

Do not edit the code that's generated by the designer.  Anything in the region marked "Windows Form Designer generated code".  Beyond losing everything you've changed when you edit the form design, you can also easily bomb the code parser.  It is not a complete C++ parser.
